# Guest allocation with Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

In our current project, we need to allocate numbers of families to hosts every weekend for lunch.

Each host can serve set number of guests (host capacity).
Each family can have different number of members.

There are several rules need to be applied before family can be assigned to the host:

1. Some families don’t want to have lunch together (meaning it can’t be assigned to a host if that other family is already assigned to it).
2. A family cannot be allocated to same host for 2 consecutive weeks.
3. Children under 13 should be no more than 50% of host capacity.
4. Families with member older than 50 should be no more than 50% of host capacity.

and few more...

Each rule can have different weight of importance i.e. if first rule breaks then family to host allocation can’t take place, but the 3rd and 4th ones might be relaxed.

This kind of problem is similar to wedding plan table arrangement, but much more complex. I have researched for few days and seems like Genetic Algorithm might be the good direction. However, I'm stuck on how to model, encode the input & implement the algorithm.

I would really appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other genetic algorithm problem, you need to make valid/partially invalid chromosomes (scenarios which can be evaluated).

One example of a chromosome can be, `W1: [{H1: F2, F3, F7}; {H2: F4, F6}; {H3: F1, F5}], W2: [{H1: F4, F3, F7}; {H2: F2}; {H3: F1, F5, F6}], ...` meaning on Week 1 (W1), Host 1 (H1) is hosting families 2, 3 and 7 and so on.

This can be generated by random assignment or other methods, known as the [Population Initialization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/genetic_algorithms/genetic_algorithms_population.htm)

Now there needs to be a way to evaluate this chromosome. Which can be done on the basis of points defined in the question.

After this some essentials functions like crossover and mutation can be thought of.

Basic examples:

```
1) for mutation, families can be shifted or switched from one host to another, 
2) for crossover, some weekends can be chosen from one parent, and some from the second, duplicate families can be adjusted.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for haven't made it clear. The allocation will be calculated for each week, so I don't think that we need to count Week in the chromosome. By the way it's a good starting point. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But then how will you account `A family cannot be allocated to same host for 2 consecutive weeks`.  And are there infinite weeks?

Comment: Yes there are infinitive weeks. On the 2nd week, I will add some additional rules based on the allocation from 1st week e.g. F1 cannot be assigned to H1 if it was allocated there previously.

Comment: Ok, then the chromosome can be `[{H1: F2, F3, F7}; {H2: F4, F6}; {H3: F1, F5}]` and you will need to iterate before finalising for every weekend.

Comment: Also since you have infinite weeks, reinforcement learning can be a better approach where your agent can learn as the weeks go by. Genetic algorithms are usually used to find a final optimised solution, e.g, when you have a fixed time frame (say 8 weeks) and you you want to pre-plan the hosting, hope this helps.

Comment: As the hosts & guests input might be changed e.g. host wants to become guest in different weekend, I think genetic algorithm may still be the better approach. Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer now. Really appreciate mate !!